# Multivariate Taylor series - little question of understanding

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

So for the case $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Generalizations_of_Taylor.27s_theorem) article develops the Taylorseries of
$f$ as follows: First, suppose $f$ is $C^{n}$ on some open ball around $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $.
Now they parametrise the line segment between $\mathbf{a}$ and some point
$\mathbf{x}$ and compute the derivative of the composite function, i.e.
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\mathrm{d}^{k}}{\mathrm{d}t^{k}}   f(\mathbf{a} + t(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}))
   = \sum_{|\alpha| = k}^{} \binom{j}{\alpha} (\mathrm{D}_{}^{\alpha}f)(\mathbf{a}+t(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}))
   (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a})^{\alpha}
.\end{align*}
I don't know whether I'm misunderstanding something, but the first derivative of $f$ can be seen as the gradient
vector $\nabla f \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $, the second derivative as the hessian matrix
$\mathbf{H}_{f} \in \mathbb{R}^{n, n} $ but doesn't one already require tensors for the derivative of the
hessian matrix (i.e. the third derivative of $f$)?

Comment: The article mentions "$D^\alpha f$" is condensed notation for the various higher order mixed partials, so is scalar,

Comment: @Golden_Ratio yes, but I don't understand why it's a scalar

Comment: Because $f$ is scalar valued. Partial derivatives of a scalar function are scalar.  See the formal definition in wiki, because  "$D^\alpha f$" is multi-index notation and can look very misleading without the context.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio but it uses the multivariable chain rule, and $f$ itself (without composition) is from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$